# Xunit in ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, xunit

I have ReSharper 6.1.1000.82 in my VS 2010 and I'm trying to install the XUnit pluging according to the instructions given I have to

> Mount a live template in Visual Studio (ReSharper -> Live Templates -> Mount file storage) and point to the copied file

But I don't have this option under my ReSharper menu but something called Templates Explorer, so I don't really know what to do.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this blog post from JetBrains](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/importing-exporting-templates-and-patterns-in-resharper-61/) says, Live Templates work rather differently in ReSharper 6.1.

The quick way to import the XUnit templates is:

1. Open the Templates Explorer from the Visual Studio "ReSharper" menu
2. On the 'Live Templates' tab, click the 'Import' icon: [image: Import]
3. Browse to one of the `xunit-ae.xml` or `xunit-xe.xml` files. You'll need to change the file type to "Old templates XML files (*.xml)" first
4. Acknowledge the warning asking if you want to import templates of type 'Live Templates'.